# How can you get a list of permissions that have been explicitly set in TFS 2010?

Tags: security, tfs, permissions

I am moving a TFS server to another machine so want the old one to be available in read-only mode.

At the top level, I have set a Windows group 'TFS Users' with Allow for the Read permission and Deny for everything else.

I want to know if there are any explicit rules set a lower levels that might conflict or override the 'global' rule.  I can click through each project then folder then file but that would take forever!

There are all the built-in and inherited rules available as you click through but it would be helpful to just get a list of any rules that are not inherited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have set Deny permission for everything else.In TFS, t**he Deny permission trumps all other permissions.**

> For most groups and almost all permissions, **Deny trumps Allow**. If a
>   user belongs to two groups, and one of them has a specific permission
>   set to Deny, that user will not be able to perform tasks that require
>   that permission even if they belong to a group that has that
>   permission set to Allow.
>
> Source Link: [Permissions versus access levels](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/connect/change-access-levels#permissions-versus-access-levels)

So you just make sure that the lower levels don't have deny the read permission which will override the allow you set for group 'TFS Users'

Moreover, to view the group permission which explicitly set, you can use [tf permission command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/permission-command) with `/group` option

*The following example displays the ACL information that relates to the group "developers" for the collection that is located at http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/.*

```
c:\projects>tf permission /group:[teamproject]\developers /collection: http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/
```

Comment: Thanks!
I used:
tf permission /server:http://myserver:8080/tfs > "c:\temp\blah.txt"
and that gave me a list that I could search for unwanted permissions.